# about Redux and firebase authentication

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making an application to practice with redux and various data states

[image: application appearance]

The idea is that an unregistered user can add cryptocurrency assets, view statistics and all that. If the user is registered, then the added assets should be saved and be in the list when logging in again

for this I decided to use Firebase Authentication and manage states using redux

I came across a situation where interaction with firebase proceeds correctly, the user is created, then the login form sees them and correctly consolidates them, but my hook, which was made to determine whether the user is logged in or not, does not work correctly

[image: inside firebase]

store

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer,
    },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

slice

```
const initialState = {
    email: null,
    token: null, 
    id: null,
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUser(state, action) {
            state.email = action.payload.email;
            state.token = action.payload.token;
            state.id = action.payload.id;
        },
        removeUser(state) {
            state.email = null;
            state.token = null;
            state.id = null;
        }
    }
})

export const {setUser, removeUser} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer
```

useAuth hook

```
export function useAuth() {
    const {email, token, id} = useAppSelector(state => state.user);
    console.log('is auth work', email, token, id)
    return {
        isAuth: !!email, 
        email,
        token,
        id,
    };
}
```

Login form
here you can see that I was already a little desperate and added isAuth to dispatch

```
interface LoginFormProps {
    onSignUp: () => void;
    onClose: () => void;
}

type FieldType = {
    email?: string;
    password?: string;
    remember?: string;
};

export function LoginForm({ onSignUp, onClose }: LoginFormProps) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(false);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const onFinish = (email: string, password: string) => {
        const auth = getAuth();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then(({user}) => {
                dispatch(setUser({
                    isAuth: true,
                    email: user.email,
                    id: user.uid,
                    token: user.refreshToken,
                }))
                console.log('user', user);
            })
            .catch();
    };

    const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo: any) => {
        console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
    };

    return (
        <Form
            name="basic"
            labelCol={{ span: 4 }}
            wrapperCol={{ span: 18 }}
            layout="horizontal"
            initialValues={{ remember: true }}
            onFinish={() => {onFinish(email, password); onClose()}}
            onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
            autoComplete="off"
        >
            <Form.Item<FieldType>
                label="Email"
                name="email"
                rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your email!' }]}
            >
                <Input
                    value={email || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }}
                />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item<FieldType>
                label="Password"
                name="password"
                rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your password!' }]}
            >
                <Input.Password
                    value={password || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }}
                />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item<FieldType>
                name="remember"
                valuePropName="checked"
                wrapperCol={{ span: 18 }}
            >
                <Checkbox
                    value={rememberMe}
                    onChange={(e) => { setRememberMe(e.target.checked) }}
                >Remember me</Checkbox>
            </Form.Item>

            <Flex gap={12}>
                <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ span: 18 }}>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Log In
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={onSignUp}>Sign Up</Button>
            </Flex>
        </Form>
    )
}
```

[image: here is what the console shows me]

This is the place where it is important for me that isAuth works correctly and I absolutely don’t understand why this doesn’t happen

```
export default function Header() {
    const { crypto } = useContext(CryptoContext);
    const [select, setSelect] = useState(false);
    const [showModal, setshowModal] = useState(false);
    const [coin, setCoin] = useState<ICryptoCurrency | null>(null);
    const [showDrawer, setShowDrawer] = useState(false);
    const [showCoinForm, setShowCoinForm] = useState(false);
    const [showLoginForm, setShowLoginForm] = useState(false);
    const [showRegistrationForm, setShowRegistrationForm] = useState(false);

    const {isAuth, email} = useAuth();

    const handleSelect = (value: string) => {
        const selectedCoin = crypto.find((c) => c.id === value)
        if (selectedCoin) {
            setshowModal(true);
            setCoin(selectedCoin);
        }
    }

    const handleAddAsset = () => {
        setShowDrawer(true);
        setShowCoinForm(true);
    }

    const handleRegistration = () => {
        setShowDrawer(true);
        setShowRegistrationForm(true);
        setShowCoinForm(false);
        setShowLoginForm(false);
    }

    const handleLogin = () => {
        setShowDrawer(true);
        setShowLoginForm(true);
        setShowRegistrationForm(false);
        setShowCoinForm(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const keypress = (event: any) => {
            if (event.key === '/') {
                setSelect((prev) => !prev);
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('keypress', keypress);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('keypress', keypress);
    }, [])

    const formNames = () => {
        if (showCoinForm) return 'Add Asset'
        if (showRegistrationForm) return 'Registration'
        if (showLoginForm) return 'Log In'
    }


    return (
        <Layout.Header style={headerStyle}>
            <Select
                open={select}
                onClick={() => setSelect((prev) => !prev)}
                style={{ width: '250px' }}
                placeholder="press / to open"
                onSelect={handleSelect}
                options={crypto.map((coin: ICryptoCurrency) => (
                    {
                        label: coin.name,
                        value: coin.id,
                        icon: coin.icon
                    }
                ))}
                optionRender={(option) => (
                    <Space>
                        <img src={option.data.icon} style={{ width: '20px', paddingTop: '6px' }} alt={option.data.id} />
                        <span> {option.data.label}</span>
                    </Space>
                )}
            />

            <Flex gap={10}>
                <Button onClick={handleAddAsset} style={addButtonStyle}>Add Asset</Button>
                {isAuth ? (
                    <Avatar icon={<UserOutlined />} />
                ) : (
                    <Button onClick={handleLogin} style={addButtonStyle}>Log In</Button>
                )}
            </Flex>

            <Modal open={showModal} style={{ maxWidth: '420px' }} onCancel={() => setshowModal(false)} footer={null}>
                <CryptoModal coin={coin} />
            </Modal>

            <Drawer
                width={600}
                destroyOnClose
                title={formNames()}
                onClose={() => {
                    setShowDrawer(false);
                    setShowCoinForm(false);
                    setShowLoginForm(false);
                    setShowRegistrationForm(false)
                }}
                open={showDrawer}
            >
                {showCoinForm && (
                    <AddAssetForm onClose={() => { setShowDrawer(false); setShowCoinForm(false) }} />
                )}

                {showLoginForm && (
                    <LoginForm onSignUp={handleRegistration} onClose={() => setShowDrawer(false)} />
                )}

                {showRegistrationForm && (
                    <RegistrationForm onLogin={handleLogin} onClose={() => setShowDrawer(false)} />
                )}
            </Drawer>
        </Layout.Header>
    )
}
```

This is the main problem for now, if I can solve it, I can move on

Answer (score 0):

found my mistake

error

```
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = () => useSelector;
```

This notation is incorrect and will cause a runtime error because it tries to return the useSelector hook itself as a function call result, rather than invoking it. The correct way to create a custom wrapper around useSelector should involve calling useSelector within the function and returning its result:

```
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = selector => useSelector(selector);
```

---

correct entry

```
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

In this notation, useAppSelector is a direct reference to the useSelector hook from react-redux. This means that when using it, you will call useAppSelector just like useSelector, passing it a selector function:

```
const user = useAppSelector(state => state.user);
```